# stretched-link not working on a div > a href (react)

Tags: href, react-bootstrap, stretched

I am trying to get a stretched-link to work without success. I have tried to add the class and set the position-relative to a parent div as requested by Bootstrap docs, and it's not working. I also tried to set the same z-index to the parent div and the link as I have seen people making it work this way, yet nothing for my case. I have the following code:

```
<div className="position-relative linkDiv">
        <a href="#AboutPage" className="stretched-link linkAbout">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="chevron"></div>
            <div class="chevron"></div>
            <div class="chevron"></div>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
```

and the css set as:

```
.linkAbout {
  z-index: 3;
}

.linkDiv {
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
}
```

If that's a matter, I didn't forget to @import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap"; to my scss file...

Any idea how to get me out of this? Thanks in advance :)

I have tried to add the class and set the position-relative to a parent div as requested by Bootstrap docs, and it's not working. I also tried to set the same z-index to the parent div and the link as I have seen people making it work this way, yet nothing for my case.

Comment: you cannot use div inside a tag, it invalid html

Comment: Hey Junaid, I am a bit confused since I am reading it actually is valid in HTML5 in several forums, ex: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/is-wrapping-a-div-inside-an-anchor-tag-valid-code#:~:text=The%20HTML5%20allows%20tag,inside%20the%20tag.

Comment: when you inspect html in your console, is ::after text generated like in this image? https://i.imgur.com/QVVf5pM.png

Comment: I do indeed but right after each "chevron" element: https://imgur.com/a/t8srJLQ

Comment: there isn't stretched-link on a tag in your above image, it cannot work without this class